# Setting bServerSide along with rowReorderingin jquery datatable cause double postback to server

Tags: jquery, datatables

My code for applying drag and drop row is below and i want rowReordering but this code is causing double postback to the server. Every time it calls server it make one more request of sAjaxSource. Is there any way by which i can prevent the double postback while using both bServerSide and rowReordering.

```
     $('#demoTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": 4,
            "sAjaxSource": "Home/AjaxHandler",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                            {
                                "sTitle": "id",
                                "sName": "Id"
                            },
                            { "sTitle": "Name", "sName": "Name" },
                            {
                                "sTitle": "Dob",
                                "sName": "Dob",
                                "sType": "date"
                            }
            ],

            "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                $(nRow).attr("id", aData[0]);
                return nRow;
            }
        }).rowReordering({ sURL: "Home/UpdateOrder" });
```

Comment: Please comment if anyone have even any idea regarding this issue

Comment: Usually when i see "bServerSide": true, the people use it without understanding what it does. Do you know what it's doing? Do you really need server side?

Comment: yes I need table body data as well as reordering from server side